# Fusion Accelerator Skins windows are blank after core upgrade to Drupal 7.1.9

Tags: theming

I just upgraded my Drupal core to 7.1.9, and now my Fusion Accelerator settings are not being applied. When I try to edit a skin (for a block), the pop-up window is empty except for the "save" button. Also, the front-end "Edit Skin" link (under the gear icon) is missing. Does anyone know what might cause this kind of issue, and how I can get my settings back so I can reapply those skin settings?

Answer (score 0):

It was a cache issue. I cleared my cache and that fixed the issue.